# Hover div to trigger animation effect in another icon

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I need to set CSS animation effects in icon when I hover my `div`.

**CSS**

```
.animated-div {
    -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
    animation-name: flipInX;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.newsline:hover .animated-div, .newsline:focus .animated-div, .newsline:active .animated-div {
    -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
    animation-name: flipInX;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box-head">
    <i class="fa fa-reorder fa-2x pull-left fa-border animated-div"></i>
</div>
</br></br></br>
<div class="newsline">test</div>
```

In action this not work!

How can I fix ?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9un5v3tj/)

Comment: You want the animation only while hovering or to happen on page load also? Also, your CSS selectors do not match the HTML structure and there is no way to trigger the effect on a previous sibling using CSS alone.

Comment: @Harry: i need to only show animated icon when i hover `DIV`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no previous sibling selector in CSS and hence the effect you need cannot be achieved using pure CSS alone without changing your markup.

**CSS Approach:**

If you can change your markup to something like below (basically move the `div` above the icon's container):

```
<div class="newsline">test</div>
<div class="box-head">
    <i class="fa fa-reorder fa-2x pull-left fa-border animated-div"></i>
</div>
```

then you can use the below CSS to trigger the animation while hovering the `div`.

```
.newsline:hover + .box-head > .animated-div {
    -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
    animation-name: flipInX;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px)
  }
}
@keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px)
  }
}
.flipInX {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible!important;
  backface-visibility: visible!important;
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
  animation-name: flipInX
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipInY {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -5deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px)
  }
}
@keyframes flipInY {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -5deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px)
  }
}
/* add this class */

.newsline:hover + .box-head > .animated-div {
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
  animation-name: flipInX;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="newsline">test</div>
<div class="box-head">
  <i class="fa fa-reorder fa-2x pull-left fa-border animated-div"></i>
</div>
```

**Selector explanation:**

```
.newsline:hover + .box-head > .animated-div
```

- Select the element with `class='animated-div'`
- which is a child of another element with `class='box-head'`
- which is in-turn the adjacent sibling of the element with `class='animated-div'`
- when the element with `class = 'animated-div'` is being hovered on.

---

**jQuery Approach:**

If you cannot modify your structure for whatever reasons, then you need to create a separate `onhover` class like given below:

```
.onhover {
    -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
    animation-name: flipInX;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

and use jQuery (or JavaScript) to add the class to the `.animated-div` while hovering on `.newsline`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.newsline').hover(function(){
        $(this).prev('.box-head').children('.animated-div').addClass('onhover');
    }, function(){
        $(this).prev('.box-head').children('.animated-div').removeClass('onhover');
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.newsline').hover(function(){
        $(this).prev('.box-head').children('.animated-div').addClass('onhover');
    }, function(){
        $(this).prev('.box-head').children('.animated-div').removeClass('onhover');
    });
});
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px)
  }
}
@keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px)
  }
}
.flipInX {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible!important;
  backface-visibility: visible!important;
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
  animation-name: flipInX
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipInY {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -5deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px)
  }
}
@keyframes flipInY {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -5deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px)
  }
}
/* add this class */

.onhover {
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
  animation-name: flipInX;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.box-head{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="box-head">
  <i class="fa fa-reorder fa-2x pull-left fa-border animated-div"></i>
</div>
<div class="newsline">test</div>
<br>

<div class="box-head">
  <i class="fa fa-reorder fa-2x pull-left fa-border animated-div"></i>
</div>
<div class="newsline">test2</div>
<br>

<div class="box-head">
  <i class="fa fa-reorder fa-2x pull-left fa-border animated-div"></i>
</div>
<div class="newsline">test3</div>
```

**Selector explanation:**

```
$(this).prev('.box-head').children('.animated-div')
```

- Select the element with `class='animated-div'`
- which is a child of an element with `class='box-head'`
- which is in-turn the previous sibling of the element that is being hovered on (that is, the element with `class='newsline'`)

If you **have any extra elements in between** the element with `class='newsline'` and the container (with `class='box-head'`) of the icon, the use the below jQuery selector instead.

```
$(this).prevAll('.box-head:first').children('.animated-div')
```

---

I have taken `hover` as a sample for both CSS and jQuery approaches but the same can be applied to the other pseudo-selectors like `active`, `focus` also.

Comment: You right. But in my design `<div class="newsline">test</div>` is below of `<div class="box-head">`.

Comment: @Perspolis: In that case, you have no option but to use JS or jQuery. CSS can't help to select any element which is above the one that is being hovered in the DOM. I have added a jQuery based example also to the answer.

Comment: Good work. Harry, in my page i have multiple `<div class="newsline">test</div>` and `<div class="box-head">` So your code not work for multiple `div`. how do work your code for multiple `div`?!

Comment: @Perspolis: Please have a look at the edit to the answer.